# How do I rotate Android orientation so the starting orientation is all 0's?

Tags: android, orientation

I am able to get the orientation of my Android phone using TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR and am able to get the angles in degrees of the 3 rotation angles. However, how do I set it so the starting orientation of the phone are all 0's? This way, regardless of starting orientation, all the measured orientations will be relative to the starting orientation -- not fixed to magnetic north, and the ground.

Answer (score 0):

I found this page:
http://www.outware.com.au/insights/which-direction-am-i-facing-using-the-sensors-on-your-android-phone-to-record-where-you-are-facing/
  and it got this working. Use TYPE_VECTOR_ROTATION with a math class from org.apache. Save you starting sensor reading, it will be a 4-element array of quaternions. Then for future readings, apply the starting reading and then get android's rotation matrix.